# Using D'Alemberts formula for a solution of a general wave equation (without specific I.C.)

Tags: wave-equation, initial-value-problems

So, I have the general wave equation
\begin{equation}
c^2u_{xx}=u_{tt}
\end{equation}

with given I.C. :

$u(x,0)=g(x)$ and  $u_t(x,0)=h(x)$

I have to use D'Alemberts formmula on the solution.

Separating variables, and equalling the two ODEs to $k^2$, I get:

The solution is for $k^2<0$

$u(x,t)=g(x)\cosh\big(\frac{k}{c^2}\big)x$

The solution for $k^2>0$:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
A\cos \frac{k}{c^2}x\cos\omega t \\
A\cos \frac{k}{c^2}x \sin\omega t\\
B\sin \frac{k}{c^2}x\cos\omega t\\
B\sin \frac{k}{c^2}x\sin\omega t
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

D'Alemberts formula is

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[g(x-ct)+g(x+ct)\bigg]+\frac{1}{2C}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}h(x)dx
\end{equation}

How is this used on the solutions given above?

Thanks

Comment: Are you working on $-\infty < x  < \infty$ or some other interval?

Comment: Hi Disintegration, This is on an infinite interval indeed!

Comment: If you use separation of variables, then you will form linear combinations of the separated solutions. In this case, the spectrum is continuous because you're working on the full real line. So, the sums turn into Fourier integrals instead. Using that approach, you would not use D'Alemberts formula, but it should work out the same, provided $g$, $h$ are in suitable spaces to make sense of the Fourier integrals.

Comment: Thanks, the question was a little bit different really. One has to prove how to derive D Alemberts formula from that eqn. THis is done by considering variable substitution of $\alpha=x+ct$ and $\beta=x-ct$

Comment: Ah, okay. That sounds like a good approach to me.